# Calculating the force on a bike chain idler sprocket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, estimation

I am trying to get a rough estimate of the force on an idler sprocket in a bike chain line, in order to get bearings robust enough for the task. Assuming a chain tension of 150 pounds and an idler with a radius of 1 inch, with a chain curving around that idler for an overall angle of 150 degrees, how do I calculate the force pushing on the bearings (or pivot point center)?
[image: idler in chain]

Comment: It's been so long since I did any basic physics, I think I thought this is more complex than it is. Nothing to do with torque? If I know the angles and the chain tension is this as simple is finding the force vectors from the chain tension as the hypotenuse, because the force I'm trying to find is the chain trying to return itself to a straight line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be just that simple, except that I don't think you ever see 150 pounds of tension at the idler: the high tension part of the chain is just the top leg, running from the chainring to the freewheel.  The lower legs, from freewheel to derailleur to idler to chainring, have much lower tension set by springs.

*Edit following comment:* The way to add forces is by vector addition: you draw the forces as arrows, and string them together head to tail, and then draw the resultant vector from the tail of the first vector to the head of the last one. In this case, there are two vectors, and they are pointed in the two directions that the chain leaves the idler; the magnitude of each is the tension, $T$. You just need to slide one over until its tail coincides with the head of the other, and you can geometrically construct the sum: the overall force, $F$, exerted on the bearing.  Using a little trig, this comes out to be $$F=2T\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}},$$ where $\theta$ is the angle through which the chain bends, i.e. zero for a chain that just brushes against the wheel, and 180 for one that bends a full halfway around and heads back the way it came.

Based on the diagram you just added, it seems that by "overall angle of 150 degrees," you mean $\theta=30$ degrees by my convention.  In this case, the result is $F=78$ lb.

Comment: Agreed, under normal circumstances, but for the current bike, there would be an idler in the tension half of the chain for purposes of deflecting it to get it to the right spot.

Comment: I see. I have expanded my answer accordingly.

Comment: This looks good and gets the same answer as the equation on this page(https://www.ropebook.com/information/angular-vector-forces/) In excel terms (where I go to iterate and check) the two working formulae are: =SQRT(2*POWER([@Tension],2)*(COS(RADIANS(180-[@Angle])))+2*POWER([@Tension],2)) AND BEN's =2*[@Tension]*SIN(RADIANS([@Angle])/2).